# How to make dashed or dotted lines in CN1 charts

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the com.codename1.charts lib but there isn't a whole lot of documentation. None of the chart demos use dashed or dotted lines and I assumed you could use BasicStroke.DASHED but changing this constant value does not seem to make a difference and keeps the line solid.

I'm using the following code:

```
colors.add(ColorUtil.GRAY);
styles.add(PointStyle.POINT);
strokes.add(BasicStroke.DASHED);
lineWeight.add(3);
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles, strokes, lineWeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be support for that. The charts were ported from Android and use a compatibility layer. That stroke class is an Android compatibility class that includes some functionality we don't support yet specifically intervals for a stroke.

You can file an issue to enhance that, basically the [BasicStroke](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/charts/renderers/BasicStroke.java) includes an `mIntervals` variable that isn't matched in [Stroke](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Stroke.java). The fix is obviously harder as the `draw` method in `Graphics` would need to account for that too and that would mean implementing that in all the native platform ports.

I'm not sure if there is a simple workaround for this.